# Start python on remote machine using batch file executed by powershell

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

I would like to run python script located on remote machine with command line arguments.

I'm using power shell command to execute batch file

```
powershell.exe -Command "invoke-command -computername testmachinename -credential testcred -scriptblock {start-process c:\test\test.bat -ArgumentList "Arg1", "Arg2"}"
```

And test.bat looks like

```
echo %time% "Started" >> C:\test\Log.txt 2>&1

set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2

echo arg1 %arg1%  >> C:\test\Log.txt 2>&1
echo arg2 %arg2%  >> C:\test\Log.txt 2>&1

cd C:\Test\

start cmd.exe
start C:\Dev\Anaconda3\python.exe test.py >> C:\test\Log.txt 2>&1
```

The echos and sets are work fine. But when it comes to execution of cmd.exe or python.exe it does nothing.

When I run batch file manually from command line on remote machine it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `start cmd.exe` why?

Comment: That is just dummy test attempt. Which I think will explain the issue. When I run the batch file manually on remote machine it opens both cmd and python shells. But when I run it from powershell frkm another mschine all works fine except starting exe part

Comment: try to run the python command directly without `start`

Comment: Already did, not working.

Comment: Any reason to use a batch file to start Python and not a PowerShell script?